# ❯ ./main [1] 87593 segmentation fault ./main

Tags: haskell

I am a novice to Haskell and Functional/Declarative Programming in general.

I don't know why I am getting a segmentation fault, from this hello world...

```hs
-- main.hs

module Main where

main = putStrLn "test"
```

What code am I missing or what is causing this error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you give more info, e.g. your OS version, `ghc --version`. What commands do you use to compile and run? How did you install GHC?

Comment: Your code is fine. Sounds like you have a bad installation of Haskell.

Comment: You will need, at least, to explain what you do to run this code — in a great detail.